# AutoCompleteTextView on MapActivity is not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-play-services, autocompletetextview

I'm new to the Android Development and I'm trying to accomplish a Android application, Where I can Search the Places using Auto-Complete and mark that place on a Google Map.

Here's my **activity_city_maps.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout_map_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CityMapsActivity">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/editText_source"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Select Source"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_source_update"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_source_update"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Set Source"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText_source"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText_source" />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_source_update"
        tools:context=".CityMapsActivity" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here my **CityMapsActivity.java** file

```
package com.softvision.gotogether.app;

//Imports hidden

public class CityMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks{

    /* AUTO-COMPLETE PROPERTIES
    * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "CityMapsActivity";
    private GoogleApiClient client;
    private static final int GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID = 0;
    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(37.398160, -122.180831), new LatLng(37.430610, -121.972090));
    private PlaceArrayAdapter mPlaceArrayAdapter;
    private AutoCompleteTextView editTextSource;


    /* MAP PROPERTIES
    * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    //Request code for location permission request.
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    //Flag indicating whether a requested permission has been denied after returning in
    private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_city_maps);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        // Location Auto complete
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(CityMapsActivity.this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();

        editTextSource = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editText_source);
        editTextSource.setThreshold(3);

        editTextSource.setOnItemClickListener(autoCompleteClickListener);
        mPlaceArrayAdapter = new PlaceArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW, null);
        editTextSource.setAdapter(mPlaceArrayAdapter);
    }

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BEGIN: LOCATION AUTO COMPLETE SECTION
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener autoCompleteClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mPlaceArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
            final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Selected: " + item.description);
            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(client, placeId);
            placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fetching details for ID: " + item.placeId);
        }
    };

    private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
            = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " +
                        places.getStatus().toString());
                return;
            }
            // Selecting the first object buffer.
            final Place place = places.get(0);
            /*
            CharSequence attributions = places.getAttributions();
            mNameTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getName() + ""));
            mAddressTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getAddress() + ""));
            mIdTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getId() + ""));
            mPhoneTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getPhoneNumber() + ""));
            mWebTextView.setText(place.getWebsiteUri() + "");
            if (attributions != null) {
                mAttTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(attributions.toString()));
            }*/
        }
    };

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    END: LOCATION AUTO COMPLETE SECTION
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Enable my location option for map.
        enableMyLocation();

        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this);

        // Creating Markers by clicking on map
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                if(markerPoints.size()>1){
                    markerPoints.clear();
                    mMap.clear();
                }

                // Add new Point
                markerPoints.add(latLng);
                options.position(latLng);

                if(markerPoints.size()==1){
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                    options.title("Source");
                    editTextSource.setText(getCompleteAddressString(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude));
                }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                    options.title("Destination");
                }
                mMap.addMarker(options);

                if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){
                    LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                    LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);
                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
                    downloadTask.execute(url);
                }
            }
        });

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener((new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                if(marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                    marker.hideInfoWindow();
                } else {
                    marker.showInfoWindow();
                }
                //.setText(myMarker.getTitle());    //Change TextView text here like this
                return true;
            }
        }));

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        /*
        LatLng destination = new LatLng(12.354509, 76.603085);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destination).title("Softvision, LLC (DBA Software Paradigms Infotech Pvt Ltd)"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(destination));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(destination.latitude, destination.longitude), 12.0f));
        */
    }

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationClick(@NonNull Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Current location:\n" + location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void enableMyLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission to access the location is missing.
            PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
        } else if (mMap != null) {
            // Access to the location has been granted to the app.
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Searching for location...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs
        // (the camera animates to the user's current position).
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,@NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            return;
        }
        if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            // Enable the my location layer if the permission has been granted.
            enableMyLocation();
        } else {
            // Display the missing permission error dialog when the fragments resume.
            mPermissionDenied = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        if (mPermissionDenied) {
            // Permission was not granted, display error dialog.
            showMissingPermissionError();
            mPermissionDenied = false;
        }
    }

    private void showMissingPermissionError() {
        PermissionUtils.PermissionDeniedDialog.newInstance(true).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }


    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BEGIN [GoogleApiClient] :Overrides for :
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallback
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(client);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connected.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(null);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connection suspended.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connection failed with error code: "
                + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Google Places API connection failed with error code:" + connectionResult.getErrorCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    END [GoogleApiClient]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Map Utility Section */
    /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    private String getCompleteAddressString(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE) {
        String strAdd = "";
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE,LONGITUDE, 1);
            if (addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");
                for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(",");
                }
                strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
            } else {
                strAdd = "No Address returned!";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            strAdd = e.getMessage();
        }
        return strAdd;
    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){
        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = String.format("origin=%s,%s", origin.latitude, origin.longitude);
        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;
        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";
        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;
        // Output format
        String output = "json";
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;
        return url;
    }

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();
            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();
            br.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";
            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }


    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>>> {
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                GmapUtility parser = new GmapUtility();
                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parseJson(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points)
                        .width(12)
                        .color(Color.parseColor("#05b1fb"))//Google maps blue color
                        .geodesic(true);
            }

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my **PlaceArrayAdapter.java** file

```
package com.softvision.gotogether.app;

/*imports hidden*/

public class PlaceArrayAdapter
        extends ArrayAdapter<PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete> implements Filterable {
    private static final String TAG = "PlaceArrayAdapter";
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;
    private LatLngBounds mBounds;
    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> mResultList;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context  Context
     * @param resource Layout resource
     * @param bounds   Used to specify the search bounds
     * @param filter   Used to specify place types
     */
    public PlaceArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, LatLngBounds bounds,AutocompleteFilter filter) {
        super(context, resource);
        mBounds = bounds;
        mPlaceFilter = filter;
    }

    public void setGoogleApiClient(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
        if (googleApiClient == null || !googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient = null;
        } else {
            mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PlaceAutocomplete getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }

    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> getPredictions(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Executing autocomplete query for: " + constraint);
            PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                    Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),mBounds, mPlaceFilter);
            // Wait for predictions, set the timeout.
            AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + status.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "Error getting place predictions: " + status.toString());
                autocompletePredictions.release();
                return null;
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                    + " predictions.");
            Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator();
            ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList<>(autocompletePredictions.getCount());
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                AutocompletePrediction prediction = iterator.next();
                resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(),prediction.getFullText(null)));
            }
            // Buffer release
            autocompletePredictions.release();
            return resultList;
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Google API client is not connected.");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Query the autocomplete API for the entered constraint
                    mResultList = getPredictions(constraint);
                    if (mResultList != null) {
                        // Results
                        results.values = mResultList;
                        results.count = mResultList.size();
                    }
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

    class PlaceAutocomplete {
        public CharSequence placeId;
        public CharSequence description;

        PlaceAutocomplete(CharSequence placeId, CharSequence description) {
            this.placeId = placeId;
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return description.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Here, when I build the application, I'm getting the following build warnings on Gradle Console and Build was successful:

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
E:\AndroidApps\GoTogether\app\src\main\java\com\softvision\gotogether\app\PlaceArrayAdapter.java:88: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type ArrayList
                resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(),prediction.getFullText(null)));
                              ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class ArrayList
E:\AndroidApps\GoTogether\app\src\main\java\com\softvision\gotogether\app\PlaceArrayAdapter.java:92: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
            return resultList;
                   ^
  required: ArrayList<PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete>
  found:    ArrayList
E:\AndroidApps\GoTogether\app\src\main\java\com\softvision\gotogether\app\GmapUtility.java:47: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type List
                            path.add(hm);
                                    ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface List
E:\AndroidApps\GoTogether\app\src\main\java\com\softvision\gotogether\app\GmapUtility.java:50: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method add in interface List is applied to given types
                    routes.add(path);
                              ^
  required: E
  found: List
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface List
E:\AndroidApps\GoTogether\app\src\main\java\com\softvision\gotogether\app\GmapUtility.java:50: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
                    routes.add(path);
                               ^
  required: E
  found:    List
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface List
5 warnings
```

And when I run the application on my device, It's crashing. Errors on Run Console as below:

```
    Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null
D/ViewRootImpl@27d899d[CityMapsActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/InputMethodManager: ISS - flag : 0Pid : 21012 view : com.softvision.gotogether.app
D/ViewRootImpl@27d899d[CityMapsActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 42 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 42 - 0, 494) or=1
I/PlaceArrayAdapter: Executing autocomplete query for: usa
E/PlaceArrayAdapter: Error getting place predictions: Status{statusCode=ERROR, resolution=null}
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `multiDexEnabled true` in your app Gradle file, inside `android {defaultConfig{}}`.

And I would suggest using the default `ArrayAdapter` instead of a custom adapter for the AutoCompleteTextView.

**EDIT:**

The standard way of using an ArrayAdapter is:

```
// The sample String array, you can use either this or List<String>
String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_of_countries);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries);
editTextSource.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Android documentation for AutoCompleteTextView: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Useful tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll try this and post the update. Can I get any  reference or samples for default ArrayAdapter ?